# Creating a mailbox in Outlook Express using a script

Tags: email, vbscript, outlook, scripting

I remember ages ago ISPs would help you get Outlook Express sorted for your new email account by getting you to download and run a .ini file that contained the settings you need.

Now I need to use one, I can't find an example of one anywhere.  Any ideas?

Comment: Are you looking to set something up for Outlook, or Outlook Express?

Comment: Ideally, a script for each, but at the moment, I'd settle for Outlook Express settings really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook Express's email account settings are stored in the registry. I've never used one of those old INI files myself, but I suspect that just modified the registry directly.

To get a feel for the values that need to be set, use RegEdit and export   `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Account Manager\Accounts`

Note that if you have multiple OE identities, the info might be in a different place than above, and will probably be at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Identities` instead.

But, I'm not sure if mucking around in a user's registry is the best way to go about it though, especially since the information could be in completely different parts of the registry if the user has multiple identities. This is probably why you don't see such INI files around anymore.

Might be better to set up a VBA config script or something more interactive.

Comment: Thanks for the post - You're quite possibly right about the .ini files not being so widely used any more.  The reason I want to use them, is that for some of my new users, I'd like to simply email them a file to their personal account, (such as Hotmail/Yahoo/Google/etc) and when they double-click it, it sets up their Outlook or Outlook Express automatically, configured to their new work email account.

But, yes, I seem to remember that they were written in VBScript... Might have a look down that route.